# Cannot populate dummy data against ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, faker, factory-boy

I am trying to create test data for a Django model in my project using [factoryboy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The data is being generated through `Faker` except one field, that is a `ManyToManyField`; a many to many relationship with another builtin model from `django.contrib.auth.model` named group.

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    is_enabled = models.BooleanField('enable voucher', default=True, help_text='A soft delete mechanism for the voucher.')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    member_roles = models.ManyToManyField(to=Group, related_name='member_roles')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.code)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Voucher'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Vouchers'
```

This is my model and this is the factory I created to generate dummy data:

```
class VoucherFactory(django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'app.Voucher'

    code = Faker('first_name')
    is_enabled = fuzzy.FuzzyChoice([True, False])
    start_date = fuzzy.FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
    end_date = fuzzy.FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))

    @factory.post_generation
    def member_roles(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return
        if extracted:
            for member_role in extracted:
                self.member_roles.add(member_role)
```

The data gets filled successfully except `voucher_member_roles` table created against this many to many relationship in `Voucher` model. I want this table to get populated also.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the member_roles when making the voucher factory. For example:

```
VoucherFactory.create(member_roles=[member_role1, member_role2])
```

See http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#simple-many-to-many-relationship where it states:

*When calling UserFactory() or UserFactory.build(), no group binding will be created.
But when UserFactory.create(groups=(group1, group2, group3)) is called, the groups declaration will add passed in groups to the set of groups for the user.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your dependencies within the factory, use:

```py
class VoucherFactory(django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'app.Voucher'

    code = Faker('first_name')
    is_enabled = fuzzy.FuzzyChoice([True, False])
    start_date = fuzzy.FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
    end_date = fuzzy.FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))

    @factory.post_generation
    def member_roles(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return
        for _ in range(2):  # <- if you want more than one
            self.member_roles.add(GroupFactory())
```